# Mixing of messages between topics in Azure Event Hubs

Tags: azure-eventhub

I am facing a different issue which is surprised to see. I have created one Event Hub namespace and within that there are 2 (a&b) event hubs with different policies. When I publish some messages to event hub "a" and I am able to subscribe the events from "b" as well. Is it something I missed in configuration? Please help.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Do you mean you can use only one token to access them both?

Comment: There are 2 event hubs. 1) eventhub1 2) eventhub2 under same namespace. Publishing events to eventhub1 and not using eventhub2. In this case, I am able to subscribe the events which is being sent to eventhub1 in eventhub2 as well which I shoudnt be able to.

Comment: so both event hubs receive to same message. Are you sure you we are talking about 2 event hubs and not 2 consumer groups?

Comment: Yes 2 event hubs not CGs